# I am Able Record Audio But The Quality Is Poor And Voice Is Coming Very low

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I am not getting clear audio and also the sound level is very low:

```
import sounddevice as sd   
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

fs = 44100  
seconds = 10 #time of recording

myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)  
sd.wait()  #waiting time
write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)
```

I am able to record the audio but the quality is poor and output voice level is very low.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the tech you are using for those who may not immediately know.

Comment: i am using iball iball compbook with windows 10 installed